# How to design a cascading regex matching the best way?

Tags: java, string

I think there must be a better design for something like this.

```
Pattern pat1 = Pattern.compile ("abc");
Pattern pat2 = Pattern.compile ("def");
Pattern pat3 = Pattern.compile ("ghi");

String str = "whatever";

Matcher mat = pat1.matcher (str);
if (mat.matches () == true)
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    mat = pat2.matcher (str);
    if (mat.matches () == true)
    {
        // ...
    }
    else
    {
        mat = pat3.matcher (str);
        if (mat.matches () == true)
        {
            ...
```

I do not like the nested ifs at all.

But I also try to avaid parsing the string for every pattern BEFORE evaluating it because of performance/efficiency.

Any idea how to make this more pretty/elegant?

Comment: store your patterns in a map. Pattern is the key, link to solution is the value. iterate over it, to find the first match

Comment: Switch to Kotlin and use `when` ;-)

Comment: As an aside, `if(mat.matches())` is more idiomatic and less error-prone than `if(mat.matches() == true)`.

Comment: `switch(str) { case "abc": … case "def": … case "ghi": … }` What is “parsing the string before evaluating” supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a more complex regular expression.

To match more than one set of characters, you can use the *|*, vertical-bar character.

*[Wikipedia – Regular expression – POSIX extended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_extended)*.

> *"The choice (also known as alternation or set union) operator matches either the expression before or the expression after the operator. For example, abc|def matches "abc" or "def"."*

```java
String string = "whatever";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("abc|def|ghi");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
if (matcher.find()) System.out.println("matched:  " + matcher.group());
```

Furthermore, if you have an array of strings, you can utilize the *[String#join](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence...))* method to concatenate them, by a vertical-bar character.

```java
String string = "whatever";
String[] strings = {
    "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqr", "stu", "vwx", "yz"
};
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(String.join("|", strings));
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
if (matcher.find()) System.out.println("matched:  " + matcher.group());
```